# Building Qt Qml Plugin using CMake

Tags: qt, cmake, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I want to compile [Qt Qml Plugin](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-cppplugins.html) using `CMake` (instead of `QMake`) and add this plugin to the some application. Plugin and application script should be in separate `CMakeLists.txt`.

File structure:

```
CMakeLists.txt
main.cpp
main.qml
qml.qrc
plugin/
    CMakeLists.txt
    MyItem.cpp
    MyItem.h
    Plugin.h
    qmldir
```

I have a script `plugin/CMakeLists.txt` that generates `libmyplugin.dylib` and `qmldir` and put it to the `plugin/MyPlugin` subfolder of plugin binary dir:

`plugin/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

add_library(myplugin SHARED
    Item.cpp
    Item.h
    Plugin.h
)

set_target_properties(myplugin PROPERTIES
    AUTOMOC TRUE
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/package/MyPlugin
)

# Copy qmldir file
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/package/MyPlugin/qmldir
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/qmldir
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E copy "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/qmldir" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/package/MyPlugin/qmldir"
    COMMENT "Copy qmldir"
)
target_sources(myplugin PRIVATE
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/package/MyPlugin/qmldir
)

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Qml Quick)
target_link_libraries(viewWorld PUBLIC Qt5::Core Qt5::Qml Qt5::Quick)
```

Now I need to build `myplugin` target before/after `app` target and copy plugin files from  `<myplugin binary dir>/plugin` into location of `app` target binary (in case of Windows and Linux) or into `<app bundle>/Contents/PlugIns` (in case of macOS):

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

add_executable(app
    main.cpp
    qml.qrc
)

set_target_properties(app PROPERTIES
    AUTORCC TRUE
)

add_subdirectory(plugin)
add_dependencies(app plugin)
# Needs to copy plugin files...

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Qml Quick)
target_link_libraries(viewWorld PUBLIC Qt5::Core Qt5::Qml Qt5::Quick)
```

I need to copy plugin files only if they changed. It would be great to write function that will take `app` target and `plugin` target and create appropriate dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my Qt projects and qml plugins I using next rules. It's actual for win platform, but I hope it will be helpfull for your macOS

Output directory is same for all projects:

```
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
```

So all sub_directories with CMakeLists and it's project targets will build into same directory. It's helpfull for project running and finnaly deploying.

Qml plugins I copy to directory

```
set_target_properties(targetProject PROPERTIES
   RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/$<CONFIG>/plugins/${QmlPluginName}/)
```

After build qml plugin I'm copy qmldir file to RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${targetProject} POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
    ${QML_DIR_FILE}
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/$<CONFIG>/plugins/${QmlPluginName}/qmldir)
```

After this steps I had hext directory structure:

```
/build_dir/bin/Debug/
           |application.exe
           |plugins/
           | |QmlPluginName/
           | | |qmldir
           | | |QmlPluginName.dll
```

So after this steps don't forget about:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.addImportPath("./plugins");
```

P.S. sorry for my English